# Git: can a project without branches have merge conflicts?

Tags: git

it may sound a stupid question but I was working only in master branch and I had a .txt file like this:

```
abc
def
```

then I changed it to

```
abc
ghi
```

then I did

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "trying to cause conflict"
$ git push
```

And it worked without any problems, the file was changed. I wondered if git cares about this case of "conflict" if the project doesn't have branches except for master.

Comment: A conflict occurs because a commit has two parents, each of which has a different version of one or more files.  In your example, the branch only has a single line, hence there can be no conflicts.  Git can completely figure out how to get from the first version to the second one.

Comment: so a conflict will only occur if the situation of the .txt file I mentioned happens, but a version coming from a branch and other version coming from another?

Comment: Yes, but even that is not guaranteed to cause a conflict.  Git _may_ be able to resolve the changes without any conflict at all.  Or, there could be a merge conflict.  Ideally, if your team plans its Git workflow well, there should be very few merge conflicts if any day-to-day.

Comment: Planning can be important - if two people work on the same file, you might easily find yourself making changes which conflict in ways which git cannot detect. For example, if one commit removes the definition of some function f and a simultaneous commit adds a call to that function, git will accept these as compatible but of course the code will fail. This is one of the many reasons for having solid tests, and using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't have any other explicit branches and you are the only one, it's still possible to have conflicts.

It can happen when the current head is diverged with the master. Technically the current head, detached or still named as master, is another branch different from the original master. Sometimes it just comes when you don't maintain the local master well. When you run 'git pull', the conflicts can happen if the current head and the remote master have different contents at the same chunk.

Another possible case is when you try to re-apply an old commit or patch. You make Commit A, and then revert it via `git revert A` to make Commit B. Later you make a new commit C which touches parts or all of the same chunks of A with different changes. Now if you cherry-pick A, conflicts come about.

When conflicts happen, have a check if the workflow is reasonable and then just resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you define "branch".

In Git, the word "branch" can mean either a branch *name* like `master`, or a branch within the *commit graph*.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

Normally, to get a branch within the commit graph, you need at least two names.  However, branches like `master` are shorthand for names that begin with the literal text `refs/heads/`: the branch `master` is really `refs/heads/master`, and if you create a branch named `A` it has the full name `refs/heads/A`.  Your Git stores these names in its own private table of name-to-hash-ID mappings.  This table also has *tag* names, like `v2.3`, which are short for names within `refs/tags/`, and what Git calls *remote-tracking branches* like `origin/master`, which are short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

If you have an `origin`, you probably have an `origin/master` to go along with your own `master`.  This gives you two names.  Only one is a *branch* name, but both may—depending on how you define "branch"—result in branches!

Besides all this, you can create anonymous branches (if you choose to call them branches in the first place) using a "detached HEAD".  You can then name commits by their raw hash IDs, and by merging such commits, create a merge conflict.  This is a way to get a conflict with only one branch *name*.  But are there multiple branches?  Again, that's up to whoever defines "branch".

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to get a merge conflict is to start on branch `alpha` and create branch `beta` off of `alpha`, and then make incompatible changes on both branches. 
In your example, you are simply changing the contents of the text file, and git will happily track that change (and revert it, stash it, use it for a cherry-pick, or whatever else you might want to do).